# WCF rest web service working on localhost but not on host

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, iis, .net-3.5

I made a simple WCF web-service inside an ASP.net website.

The web-service is hosted by **IIS** and works fine on localhost, ie when accessing for exemple to
http://localhost/myservice.svc/HelloWorld  I get the correct "Hello World" response as expected.

But accessing to it by my computer hostname ( http://mycomputer/myservice.svc/HelloWorld ) gets me an error 404 response. This is particularly confusing as the remaining of the site (mainly aspx pages) is accessible without any problem from both ways.

I suspect a configuration issue in IIS, but I have no real clue. Any help would be really appreciated.

My service endpoint is the following:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Service" />
```

The error stacktrace from the server is the following:

```
[EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://mycomputer.ad-ent.lan.net/myservice.svc/HelloWorld'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
[HttpException]: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://mycomputer.ad-ent.lan.net/myservice.svc/HelloWorld'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   à System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext)
   à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   à System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   à System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: What's in your web.config - the <endpoint> and <binding> elements? I can't see anything for those in MSDN that would restrict it to localhost only but I'm not an expert here, and I'd guess that's where the problem would have to be.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: What happens when you right click on the svc file in iis admin and select "Browse"?

Comment: I am running IIS 7.5.  When i right click on the svc file and select browse, the service page (at localhost) is opened inside my browser and work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this over on server fault. https://serverfault.com/questions/107592/localhost-works-but-computer-name-does-not

Comment: He says that he can access .aspx pages using the non-local-IP, though, so it doesn't sound like that to me.

Comment: Install wireshark and see what it's doing. It may give you a clue on where the request is going. http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the NATs and firewall settings with your server, check out the following article

[Working with NATs and Firewalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731948.aspx)

Comment: My server is located on my computer itself, and the corresponding port (80) is wide open as shows the rest of the website working. The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Very old post, I know. But for the sake of history and knowledge; Chances are you are using a proxy, in this case, you need to add exception for your computer name in the your browser settings.