# Web service(asmx) works perfectly on localhost but not on local ip address

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, localhost, asmx

As mentioned in the question, I have deployed my service on IIS and using my computer ip address "111.111.111.1:100 and also specify the port (100).

I also checked if the port was listening which it is. The service deploys with no problem. I can also see the asmx file however when I open it is just blank. I have done some research before posting this question but didn't find and valid answer to my question. Hopefully will find it here. Thanks in advance.

Research made
[WCF rest web service working on localhost but not on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471634/wcf-rest-web-service-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-host)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/823b076c-160d-4f52-86ad-c84dfb91accb/webservice-running-on-localhost-but-not-running-with-full-server-name?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: `I have done some research before posting this question but didn't find and valid answer to my question.`  - Can you provide examples or the outcome of that research so people don't suggest the same things that you may have already tried?

Comment: @Darkoj1 I edited my post and added a couple

Comment: what do you mean by `I can also see the asmx file however when I open it is just blank`? As in you try to open it in a browser or you open the deployed file?

Comment: @JustinCervero sorry for the late reply and yes that's exactly it

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your firewall settings? Maybe the firewall is blocking the port you are using